# Is it possible to concatenate two files on the same linux filesystem by modifying the inode datastructure and superblock?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, inode, filesystem-access

If I want to concatenate two very large files residing on the same filesystem, say ext3 or ext4 for example, does linux provide an api to do it programmatically by reading and modifying the inode direct/indirect pointers of the two files, and modifying the filesize and superblock values? If so, is there any documentation on the api/headerfiles for that?

Note: I am aware of built in linux binaries like cat, tee, etc which could be used, but my question is about programmatically achieving this.

Comment: What if the size of the first file is not a multiple of the filesystem block size?

Comment: That's a good question @dbush. Doing the math and rewriting the blocks if possible at all, would make it like a normal concatenation, or worse I guess. Is this possible if the filesize is a multiple of blocksize?

Comment: I don't think this operation is supported. That would really surprise me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, depending on what *concatenate* means, and how low level the code doing the work is, and what the file system is.

1. Low level, impractical, difficult, especially for *ext3* & *ext4*.  Suppose we wish to do the equivalent of `cat foo bar | sponge foo`, but without anything but metadata being read or overwritten.  In this case *foo* would have to be an exact blocksize multiple, and the trick would be to get the inodes and dir structure of both files, `rm bar`, unmount the file system, and tweak the relevant [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) however you please, (say `dd` and some hex editor), in such a way as not to wreck anything else.
   Depending on the file system that might be difficult, and require updating or modifying some other affected or obstructing data structure.
   If *foo* is not an exact blocksize multiple there'd be garbage data in the middle of the concatenated file.
2. Cheat.  Use a file system with [in-line deduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication#In-line_deduplication).  [*Btrfs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) should have that feature [someday.](http://lwn.net/Articles/679031/)